# How to use htpasswd For CKAN Instance

Tags: python, apache, tomcat6, .htpasswd, ckan

I have included Location header in My Virtual Host file.

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
require valid-user

Also created user to access the domain. but the user i have created using htpasswd is not allow other user to make any activity in CKAN Instance.
anyone Have an idea..Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You are using nginx, arent you?

So you can make the athentification with nginx with just adding two lines to one file and creating a password file.

In /etc/nginx/sites-available/ckan add following lines:

auth_basic "Restricted";

auth_basic_user_file /filedestination;

then create create a file at your filedestination with following content:

USERNAME:PASSWORD

The password must be in md5.

Have fun with ckan!

Comment: I am using apache not nginx